# Use InsertAdjacentHtml by Powershell with IE COM

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use  InsertAdjacentHtml with IE COM by Powershell but my code fails what can be the reason ?

```
$oIE = new-object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$oIE.visible=$True
$oIE.navigate2("http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/getElementsByName.html")
While ($ie.Busy) {
Sleep 2
}
$doc = $oIE.Document
$btns = $doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
$btns.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="secondDiv">Second</div>');

$oIE.visible=$True
```

The comand line shows Invalid Operation error

Comment: Please add more details about the issue.  Include what behavior you're observing and what behavior you expect.  For example, what do you mean by "my code fails"?  Does it return an error, or just not have the intended effect?  If error, include the details of the error.  Which line of code is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your script both line by line and by saving it as a PowerShell script, but got different results - both were errors.

When running line by line, I get this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'insertAdjacentHTML'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $btns.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="secondDiv">Second</div>');
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (insertAdjacentHTML:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Altough the method 'insertAdjacentHTML' is listed with Get-Member, it cannot be used.

So, I wanted to find a reason for that or another way to achieve the same thing. I ended up with this conclusion: PowerShell might not be the best tool to achieve what you are trying for OR you should use objects that have more reliable methods.

When I run an altered script, line by line, it sort of works:

```
$oIE = new-object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$oIE.visible=$True
$oIE.navigate2("http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/getElementsByName.html")

$doc = $oIE.Document
$btn = $doc.all.item("test", 1)
$btn.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="secondDiv">Second</div>')

$oIE.visible=$True
```

This is the HTML produced:

```
<div id="test">
    <p name="test">This is a paragraph with name="test"</p>
    <ppk name="test">This is a ppk tag with name="test"</ppk>
    <p><input name="test"><div id="secondDiv">Second</div>This is an input with name="test"</p>
    <p><img name="test">This is an image with name="test"</p>
</div>
```

To make things even stranger, this only works in a normal PowerShell console, it fails when using PowerShell ISE.

**EDIT:** Try it with a ForEach loop, it just might work. It occurred to me that you cannot run a method on an array of objects unless you call it within a loop AND another thing, that the page the script was navigating to might have issues.

So, this works:

```
$oIE = new-object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$oIE.visible = $True
$oIE.navigate2("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650033/use-insertadjacenthtml-by-powershell-with-ie-com/")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3333

$doc = $oIE.Document
$btns = $doc.getElementsByName("_id_")
$btns | ForEach-Object { $_.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="secondDiv">Second</div>') }
```

Thank you for the question, this is nice to know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I also can't find the reason why this is not reliable way. - from the first glance- it is a com.object and should be able to use its methods (as insertAdjacentHTML is a documented method.) May be you could give another idea how is it possible to modify webpage in IE- may be something like JS injection?